# Wait for task to finish and call another one instead of fixed wait_time in locust

Tags: python, locust

Assume I have a MyUser like this that executes `dosomething` every 5 seconds.

```py
from locust import HttpUser, task, constant

class MyUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = constant(5)

    @task
    def dosomething(self):
        self.client.get("/doing")
```

Instead of doing the task `dosomething` every 5 seconds, I want locust to constantly execute a new `dosomething` whenever it finishes an old one.

Is it possible to do that in locust or we must always have a fixed wait_time ?

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#wait-time-attribute

Comment: @VishalSingh As I know the `between`, `constant_throughput` and `constant_pacing` require an approximate time for each task (correct me if i'm wrong because I'm new to locust), but I want to do task as soon as it finishes the previous one so I think those settings won't help.

Comment: Maybe read that one more time: ”If no wait_time is specified, the next task will be executed as soon as one finishes”

Comment: Many thanks VishalSingh, Cyberwiz, I carelessly miss that part. Glad you guys help me ^^